# java: updating a hashmap automatically

Tags: java, date, timer, hashmap

so right now i have a hashmap which stores Calendar objects (just need a way to store dates). each value stores two Calendar objects, one representing the start of an event, and the other the end of it. The user enters these through a gui, and they can span weeks and months.

What i need to do is be able to remove these entries when they expire, meaning their second Calendar object has passed according to the real world date.  I want this to be done automatically as long the instance is running.

My idea was to have a timer thread running and once a week it could go through all the entries in the hashmap and remove the ones that have expired.  I know its not all that practical, its for a school project. But I was just looking for ideas or design pattern that could help implement this in an efficient manner.

Thanks and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Without dedicating a thread (which counts down to expiration) to each entry, this is probably your best choice.

Comment: You can take a look at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm
and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel! [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) already do this for you and let's you configure the algorithm to *update* your cache (map).

Answer (score 1):

Having a background thread that performs maintenance tasks is a good idea and is very common practice. Be warned though that a Hashmap is not thread safe so you will need to synchronize its access, or replace with a thread safe class such as ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: ah i see, thank you. The main thing i was worried about was whether this timer thread practice is any good or not, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Calendar` will only lead to grief - it's a terrible class, loaded with pitfalls and bugs.

Instead, store the start and end as `long` values, as per [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) and compare these with [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29), to keep things clean and simple.

Comment: Ya i guess, i dont really need the calendar object for any other purpose, thnks.

Comment: Though I am also against storing Calendar, I think it is better to store them as Date instead.  As long as you don't touch those deprecated methods in Date, Date can be treated as a immutable value object which is safe to use, and it give semantic meaning

Comment: @AdrianShum You're quite wrong about `Date` being safe: The [`Date.setTime(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setTime(long)) method is *not* deprecated, but torpedoes immutability!

Comment: what if i need to set a future date, is it still okay to use the set methods then just immediately use getTime and store it as a long?

Comment: @Bohemian Agree :)  I have really overlooked that.  However I still prefer storing as `Date`, as `long` still didn't give the semantic meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is useful for:
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained
Guava has a "caching"-mechanism, that handels timeouts, ...

So the handling is made for you, but take care: There is no thread running in the background. The maintaince is done during the wirtes. Infos are contained in the link too.

The guava-solution "explains" the other way.
Why not handling a list/map of timeout-elements which tell you during the access, that they timed out, or shutdown on their own.
You don't have to manage the elements from the outside, they could handle the timeout on their own.
This way is ofter quite simple and transparent to the user.

Comment: thanks this actually looks really good. Hope it just works out fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instead a TreeSet

```
TreeSet<DateObject> yourTreeSet = new TreeSet<DateObject>(new DateComparator());
```

Then implement your comparator, and the objects will be sorted as you add them in the TreeSet

Answer (score 0):

The other option can be to instantiate a [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) for every entry. Implement its `run()` method to remove the entry from the map, at [`schedule()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29) time -- which is probably end time in your case. That way, you don't need weekly clean-up and the entries will be removed as soon as they expires.

And of course, take care of thread safety, perhaps by using some [thread-safe variant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), I mean `Map` implementations.

**[Edited]**

Or still better, use [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), instead.